# Basic issue re scoping in create-react-app / webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am a relative newcomer to react, though I have created one functioning react app using `create-react-app`.

One of the selling points of react seems to be that you can migrate code piecemeal rather than all at once. I am now migrating an existing web app, and trying to see if I can get it to function within the create-react-app ecosystem with minimal modification; step 2 will be to react-ize it. I am stuck at step 1. (I think I have managed step 0—getting it to compile at all—although that took a long time.)

I have replaced the `create-react-app` `index.html` with my own `index.html`, and the `create-react-app` `index.js` with my own main js file, renamed to `index.js`. In the past, my main file was loaded with a `<script>` tag from `index.html`, and all its functions went into the global scope. Apparently now they are not going into the global scope.

In `index.html`, I have:

```
<button type="button" id="connectButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="connect()">
    Log on
</button>
```

In `index.js`, I have:

```
function connect() { 
    ... 
}
```

In the past clicking the button would invoke the function, because it was in the global scope. Now, clicking on the button generates "`ReferenceError: connect is not defined`," because apparently it is not going into the global scope.

Someone downvoted my original version of this question, perhaps because I'm asking about something that is not "the react way of doing things." I am completely aware of that, but the way to get people to do things "the react way" is to show them a way that they can migrate their codebases incrementally. So I can't imagine I'm the only person who's had this problem. My attempts at googling didn't seem to come up with anything helpful, though.

Addendum: I see that I can work around this by inserting `window.connect = connect;` after the function definition, which puts it in the global scope. I will add that as an answer to this question, but maybe someone has a better explanation or workaround, in which case I will accept their answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using an onclick handler via the HTML file instead of React?

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: @Li357: I intend to migrate to react, but I was hoping to do it piece-by-piece.

Comment: @wgcrouch: the HTML is `<button type="button" id="connectButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="connect()">Log on</button>`. The button renders correctly. The body of the function is long, and not terribly interesting; it compiles without errors and log statements just before and after the definition are both executed. I can show the full code if that would be helpful, but it doesn't seem like it would be, since the function is not being executed.

Comment: Maybe downvoters could supply a reason? If this is not a legitimate question, I would like to know why.

Comment: its saying `connect` is not defined, have you defined it? If this is just in html, then is `connect` in the global scope, or the scope that that html is generated? Without the rest of the code its hard to help

Comment: Thanks @wgcrouch, I have edited the question extensively to make it clearer, and in the process I figured out a workaround that I documented there, so I appreciate your encouragement to be more precise. If you have further thoughts, they are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remarked in the edited version of the question, inserting `window.connect = connect;` after the function definition puts it in the global scope, and so seems to be an effective workaround.